# find the highest number in an array made by the method

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

There is a class for passengers which contain `string name`, `int age`, `string job` etc. I made an array of this class, lets say it has 10 places.
I wanna find the oldest passenger.

My code doesn't work, because it is not possible to compare `passenger[i]` with an integer. I mean I need only the `age` in `passenger[]`

How to find the oldest one in `passenger[]`?

EDIT: The return value should be a `passenger` by his `name` and `major`, not only its `age`.

```
public Passenger Oldest()
{
    int oldest = 0;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < passengers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (passengers[i] > oldest)
        {
            oldest = passengers[i];
        }
    }
  
    return oldest;
}

    
class Passenger
{
    int age;
    string name;
    string major;
    
    public Passenger(int _age, string _name, string _major)
    {
        age = _age;
        name = _name;
        major = _major;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `passengers[i].age` for `oldest` and comparison?

Comment: ^--- This plus note that `oldest` is an `int`, but the method expect a type `Passenger` to be returned

Comment: `age`, `name` and `major` are [`private`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private). You can't access them from outside of the class `Passenger`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as mentioned by @Cid in comment to question all fields of `Passenger` are `private` (by default when modifier is not specified). You should either mark then as `public` (to access them outside declaring class) or better create public properties:

```
class Passenger
{
    public int Age { get; set; } // public auto property
    public string Name { get; set; } // public auto property
    public string Major { get; set; } // public auto property

    public Passenger(int age, string name, string major)
    {
        Age = age;
        Name = name;
        Major = major;
    }
}
```

Secondly, you need to compare `Age` (proeprty, not whole object) of the passenger:

```
if (passengers[i].Age > oldest)
{
    oldest = passengers[i].Age;
}
```

Also, you could use `LINQ` to find the oldest passenger:

```
var oldest = passengers.Max(item => item.Age);
```

Finally, to return the oldest passenger:

```
public Passenger Oldest()
{
    // if no passengers -> return null
    if (!passengers?.Any() ?? true)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var maxAge = passengers.Max(item => item.Age);
    
    return passengers.First(item => item.Age == maxAge);
}
```

Also, as mentioned by @DmitryBychenko the method can be shortened to:

```
public Passenger Oldest()
{
    // if no passengers -> return null
    if (!passengers?.Any() ?? true)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return passengers.Aggregate((s, a) => s.Age > a.Age ? s : a);
}
```

or without `LINQ`:

```
public Passenger Oldest()
{
    // if no passengers -> return null
    if (passengers == null || passengers.Length == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var maxAge = passengers[0].Age;
    var oldestPassengerIndex = 0; 
 
    for (var i = 1; i < passengers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (passengers[i].Age > maxAge)
        {
            oldest = passengers[i].Age;
            oldestPassengerIndex = i;
        }
    }
  
    return passengers[oldestPassengerIndex];
}
```

Comment: Linq solution can be shortened into `return passengers.Aggregate((s, a) => s.Age > a.Age ? s : a);`

Comment: Without LInq method can be shortened as well if we turn `for` loop into `foreach` one: `Passender oldest = null; foreach (var p in passengers) if (oldest == null || p.Age > oldest.Age) oldest = p; return oldest;`

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq is easy

```
var oldest=passengers.Max(x=>x.Age):
```

Otherwise

```
Passenger oldest=new Passenger(0,"","");
foreach (Passenger p in Passengers){
   if (p.age>oldest.age) oldest=p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more efficient version of Roman's answer, especially if the oldest passenger appears last in the list:

```
public Passenger Oldest()
{
    if (passengers.Length == 1) return passengers[0];

    var oldest = passengers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < passengers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (passengers[i].Age > oldest.Age) oldest = passengers[i];
    }
    return oldest;
}
```

This only ever requires a single iteration.